# Application fails to start due to kafka streams store is waiting to be running

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a spring boot application working with kafka streams (kafka docker image: `wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.1.1`, kafka dependencies: `org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.4.1`). 
During application start up I check whether or not topic my-topic is created, if not - application creates it. After that application creates `KTable` like:

```
streamsBuilder.table("my-topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()), Materialized.as("my-topic-store"))
```

And further, I create store in order to query it:

```
while(true)
    try{
        return kafkaStreams.store("my-topic-store", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()) 
    } catch (InvalidStateStoreException e) {
        log.info("Waiting for store {} is RUNNING", "my-topic-store");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

My application is deployed in k8s. When new version of application is ready, k8s starts new application and scales down old one.
The problem is when new application starts up, I see in logs only multiple lines like: "Waiting for store my-topic-store is RUNNING.

I tried to dig into the problem. From kafka documentation, 1 partition is read by only 1 consumer, and 1 consumer can read from multiple partitions. If new consumer comes and all partitions already 'occupied', this consumer becomes idle. In our case, when new application starts up, means new consumer is coming, it becomes idle because old application with old consumers is still working, therefore new consumer is not able to listen kafka partition. 
I should notice, that application is configured with 5 threads for kafka streams, and there are 23 topics at all each of them with 1 partition (I tried to change partition number from 1 to 5, but it did not help). Application redeployment is happened with no load at all.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question: the title say "fails to start" while the text says: `I see in logs only multiple lines like: "Waiting for store my-topic-store is RUNNING.` -- It's expected that the store is not available during a rebalance, and it seems the log message only appears a few time and go away. So what it the problem? -- Also note, if there is an existing consumer and new consumer starts, the new consumer will get partitions assigned in general. The old consumer will get partitions revoked during a rebalance.

Comment: Hi Matthias, thank you for your reply. Sorry, I confused with my title. In my case, when I start application for the 1st time - everything works fine. When I want to deploy new instance, for example, new version of app, I expect that new instance will be initialized, store will be created and running and old instance will stop after that. But when I start new instance, this store will not be running at all. There is only 1 workaround I found: stop the old version and only after that start the new one.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe (in the comment) is expected behavior.

When you start the new app, it will join the consumer group. Because there is only one partition, the new app does not get any work assigned (there is no reason to re-assign work because it would just be an expensive state migration; note that from a rebalancing point of view, you application scaled out; it's unknown that you plan to stop the already existing app).

When you finally stop the old app, work (and state) is reassigned.

Also note that starting a new instance would never stop any existing instance. Instead, as mentioned already, it's considered a scale out of your application.

The recommended way to upgrade an application is to stop the old instance first, and restart the new instance on the same server so it can pick up the state from the old instance from disk. This avoids expensive state migration.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, that is what I`m doing now: stopping old instance and starting new one.